# If you "ride something", do you control it or simply sit behind/aside?

Tags: ambiguity

I remember my friend telling that she rides a bus to go to her office. I also remember my another friend telling that she rides a scooter to go to her office.

Does it mean that I need to identify **the type of vehicle** to guess whether she rode (drove) or travelled by?

Imagine my **first friend is a bus-driver** and second friend **does not know how to drive a two-wheeler**! It'll create a disaster! What say?

Comment: S.R. Hadden: *They still want an American to go, Doctor. Wanna take a ride?* --*[Contact](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118884/quotes?item=qt1542424)* (1997)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is another case where context is everything.

If the sentence is talking about a single person vehicle like a bicycle, scooter or motorbike then "ride" means to "sit on and control". A similar meaning also applies if you're talking about a horse, camel or other ridable animal.

If you're talking about a larger vehicle like a car, bus or train "ride" means "to travel in a vehicle" and strongly implies that the person is a passenger rather than the driver.

There's another wonderfully ambiguous way of talking about public transport. Your friend could also say that she "takes the bus to the office" which would usually mean the same as riding the bus; i.e. that she travels on the bus as a passenger. It doesn't mean that she engages in vehicle theft!

Comment: Oops...in India, bicycle, scooter or motorbike is **never** a single-person vehicle! http://newshopper.sulekha.com/india-elections_photo_805316.htm AND http://www.loupiote.com/photos/3707875815.shtml hahaha....

Comment: Hah, fair point. In guess in such cases the use of "ride" could be ambiguous since everyone is riding in one sense but only one person is in control (hopefully!).